# subprocess.callでdateコマンドを実行できない

Tags: python, python3, linux

以下のようなコマンドを実行したいのですが、正しい書式が分かりません。どのように修正したら良いでしょうか？

```
subprocess.call("date —set="2017/01/01 01:02:03"")
```

追記:
実行しようとするとこの行に対して以下の内容
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
というエラーが出て実行できないため、書式エラーと判断しました。

Comment: スタック・オーバーフローへようこそ！　「実行できない」とのことですが、エラーが出ているのか、エラーは出ないけれど思ったように動かないのか、その場合どのような挙動なのか、などの情報が欲しいです。質問文下の「編集」から追記いただけないでしょうか？

Comment: エラーについて追記いたしました。よろしければご確認下さい。

Answer (score 1):

文字列に `"` を入れるには `\"` と書くか `'` で囲みます。

```
subprocess.call("date -set=\"2017/01/01 01:02:03\"")
```

```
subprocess.call('date -set="2017/01/01 01:02:03"')
```

また、リスト形式で指定すれば日付を囲む引用符がいらないはずです。

```
subprocess.call(["date", "-set=2017/01/01 01/02/03"])
```

Comment: リストでコマンドと引数を分離する方法がよいと思います。`subprocess.call('date -set="2017/01/01 01:02:03"')`は`date -set="2017/01/01 01:02:03"`がひとつのコマンドと解釈されそうです。`shell=True`を指定すれば大丈夫かもしれませんがセキュリティ面で注意が必要が必要です(今回の場合は大丈夫そう)。